# How many height arrangements are there for people?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's suppose $n$ people of different height stand in line, and the observer (who is smaller than the people in line) looks at them from the side. The observer sees a person unless there is a taller person between them. For example, in permutation `[2, 1, 3, 4]`, the observer (on the left) sees 3 people: everybody except for `1`.

How many arrangements (permutations) of $n$ people are there in which the observer sees $k$ people?

I need a formula (or algorithm) which is faster to compute than checking all $n!$ permutations for the number of people seen.

Comment: You can denote the arrangements with a $+$ and a $-$ depending on the adjacent number. In the example shown, it is $+-++$. Now the problem reduces to finding how many arrangements have exactly $k$  $+$'s.

Comment: @Shailesh: This is not true, for example: `[2, 1, 3, 4]`, `[4, 1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 1, 2, 4]` all translate to $+$ $-$ $+$ $+$.

Comment: Yes you are right. Did not think of that. Sorry.

Comment: I don't understand. 2 is on the left. How come s(he) can't see 1 ? Also is the tallest 1 or 4 ?

Comment: @trueblueanil: 4 is the tallest. The observer can't see 1, because 2 is blocking the view ($2 > 1$).

Comment: With 4 people in [ ], working out seeing 1,3 or 4 is relatively simple. Seeing 2 is a bit tricky, and will become trickier as *n* increases....

Comment: 3 • • 4 • • For placing 1 & 2 in two of the four possible spots, (and worse when *n* increases), we can't use simple permutations/combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the persons have lengths $1,2,\dots,n$

Let $a_{n,k}$ denote number of arrangements that you mention in your
question.

Then $a_{n,k}=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k+1}a_{n,k,m}$ where $a_{n,k,m}$ denotes
the number of these arrangements with the person with length $m$
is *on the left*.

So first we place this person.

Then we place the $n-m$ persons with a length $>m$ on a row on the
right side of the person with length $m$. There are $a_{n-m,k-1}$
arrangements for them.

Then we place the $m-1$ with length $<m$ one by one also on the
right side of the person with length $m$. There are $\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-m\right)!}$
arrangements for them.

This tells us that $a_{n,k,m}=a_{n-m,k-1}\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-m\right)!}$
hence: $$a_{n,k}=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k+1}a_{n-m,k-1}\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-m\right)!}$$

So we have a recursion formula.